# SCSS / SASS to CSS in special folder with PHPstorm 7 file watcher

Tags: css, sass, directory, phpstorm, watch

I used PHPstorm 6 and my SCSS-Files were compiled into the CSS-Folder, so I have:

```
css
  -- main.css
img
js
scss
  -- main.scss
  -- _variables.scss   ...
```

Hier are my definitions on SCSS File Watcher
[image]

Everthing worked fine, but yesterday I updated my PHPstorm from version 6 to 7 and now my SCSS compile / file watcher are not working anymore. The File Watcher compile the CSS-File into the SCSS-Folder. But I want it in my CSS-Folder!!!

What are your settings in PHPstorm 7 Filewatcher for SCSS Files?

here is my data structure, you'll see the file style.css with FileDirName/css/style.css one folder "to high" ..
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

AAAAAAArrrgh!

the "backslashes" were the problem.

output path

```
$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

[image]

Comment: Even Windows is picky about this, as I've just found out.  Windows doesn't normally care, but seems to for the PhpStorm watchers.

Comment: Thanks! This is poorly documented in the PHPStorm Docs.

Answer (score 18):

To place rendered with PHPStorm File Watcher css file in css directory and keep sass file in sass directory I've changed Arguments and Output paths to refresh.

Arguments field:

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css --style expanded
```

you can remove `--style expanded` if you want to see css with additional spaces as it is looking in sass. this argument is only changing the indents in css file to old fashioned and drupal requires this.

and Output paths to refresh field:

```
$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```