# PHPStorm 7 File Watcher ignores configuration

Tags: sass, compass-sass, phpstorm

I'm trying to set up a Compass project. Everything seem to work when I compile manually. However, when I'm using a File Watcher it saves it in the same directory as the SCSS file.

I just want the File Watcher to use my configuration file. Preferably on every project in the future.

**Right:** Structure when compiled manually

[image: Manual]

**Wrong:** Structure when compiled with the File Watcher

[image: File Watcher]

---

config.rb

```
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "css/sass"
output_style = :compressed
```

File Watcher

[image: File Watcher]

---

How can I make the File Watcher to respect the configuration?

Comment: config.rb -- no idea, sorry. But you can easily change it by editing your File Watcher parameters (Arguments field) -- just like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587558/scss-sass-to-css-in-special-folder-with-phpstorm-7-file-watcher

Comment: @LazyOne `config.rb` is a file used for [**Compass**](http://compass-style.org/), which is a SASS extension. I forgot that PHPStorm associates `scss` files with SASS projects instead of Compass projects. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: Yes, I know what is Compass and what config.rb is for. By "no idea" I meant "I do not know how to make it to obey that file".

Comment: @LazyOne I totally misunderstood that, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

- Deleted the **SCSS** File Watcher
- Manually added a **Compass** File Watcher
- Set arguments to: `compile $ProjectFileDir$`

[image: Settings]